# How to add a value in each variable in a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I try to increase the values to increase each iteration so that they do not repeat. Thus, where the value in the line ended, in the next the value at the beginning of the line will be higher by one.
In the output I have it shown as it should be
It works, but I would need to put it in a for loop so that the value increases automatically. So that I don't have to add values manually as I have now

```
import numpy as np
maxv=6
dlzka_ohr=dlzka_ohr

    totalizer_x=np.arange(maxv,maxv+dlzka_ohr)
    totalizer_y=np.arange(maxv+dlzka_ohr,maxv+dlzka_ohr+dlzka_ohr)
    totalizer_z=np.arange(maxv+dlzka_ohr+dlzka_ohr,maxv+dlzka_ohr+dlzka_ohr+dlzka_ohr)
    print(totalizer_x,'x')
    print(totalizer_y,'y')
    print(totalizer_z,'z')
```

output

```
[5 6 7 8] x
[ 9 10 11 12] y
[13 14 15 16] z
```

Can anyone advise me how to loop it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just do this:

```
size = 4
start = 5
end = 16
arrays = [list(range(i, i + size)) for i in range(start, end, size)]

x = arrays[0]
y = arrays[1]
z = arrays[2]
```